# Logback coloring based on class/package

Tags: java, logging, colors, logback, separation-of-concerns

I've started reading about Logback (currently using log4j and thinking about switching).
I'm interested in the possibilities to color the logged messages.
Browsing through previous questions, I've only seen mentions of coloring different parts of the message (conversion patterns) or coloring exceptions.

What I'm interested in, however, is whether logback can color my messages based on their package or class.

For example, let's say my application is composed of two main components- a producer and a consumer, and they both are composed of a large dependency tree. Can I have any message which is logged through the consumer colored red, and any message which is logged through the producer colored blue?

Please notice that I don't want this to interfere with log levels (that is, I still want to have the option to set components to debug/error etc, ideally without having to mind the coloring.

Thanks!